# How do I fix the "invalid expression: missing" error in v-bind:style?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, debugging

I was trying to add a v-bind:style to the following element but got this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: missing : after property id in

    {background-color: bg_color, color: txt_color}

  Raw expression: v-bind:style="{background-color: bg_color, color: txt_color}"


1  |  <div v-bind:style="{background-color: bg_color, color: txt_color}" id="app">
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2  |  
3  |              <header>

(found in <Root>)
```

And this is my code:

```
var vueinst = new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data: {
        dark_mode: false,
        bg_color: '#FFFFFF',
        txt_color: '#333533'
    },
    computed: {
        change_mode: function(){
            if(this.dark_mode == true){
                this.bg_color = '#333533';
                this.txt_color = '#F5CB5C';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My question is how can I fix this error?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think if you add single quotes around ***background-color*** it will resolve the error
as vue.js documentation says

The Object syntax for v-bind:style is pretty straightforward - it looks almost like CSS, except it’s a JavaScript object. You can use either camelCase or kebab-case for the CSS property names:

**camelCase** (no quotes necessary around the key):

```
<div :style="{ backgroundColor: bgColor, color: txtColor}" />
```

**kebab-case** (quotes necessary around the key):

```
<div :style="{ 'background-color': bgColor, color: txtColor}" />
```

[https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#:~:text=The%20object%20syntax%20for%20v-bind%3Astyle%20is%20pretty%20straightforward,%7D%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20data%3A%20%7B%20activeColor%3A%20%27red%27%2C%20fontSize%3A%2030%20%7D](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#:%7E:text=The%20object%20syntax%20for%20v-bind%3Astyle%20is%20pretty%20straightforward,%7D%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%20data%3A%20%7B%20activeColor%3A%20%27red%27%2C%20fontSize%3A%2030%20%7D)

> The Object syntax for v-bind:style is pretty straightforward - it
> looks almost like CSS, except it’s a JavaScript object. You can use
> either camelCase or kebab-case for the CSS property names: I know its
> old version but this is still applied.

(I attached old link because
vue.js's ne guide don't have these exact words)

Comment: update me if it works out !

Comment: Please add a link to the referenced documentation.